# Limit object properties in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I'm receiving data through a service, but want to reduce the amount of data in my scpoe variables and am wondering the best practice for doing this.

Data received:

```
    $scope.mainObject {
        id: ...,
        name: ...,
        type: ...,
        color: ...,
        size: ...,
        location: ...,
        arrayObjects: [
            {
                keepProp: ...,
                keepProp2: ...,
                removeProp: ...,
                arrayObjects2: [
                    keepProp: ...,
                    keepProp2: ...,
                    removeProp: ...,
                    removeProp2: ...
                ]
            },
            {
                keepProp: ...,
                keepProp2: ...,
                removeProp: ...,
                arrayObjects2: [

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Sorry for the crude data, above. I have an objects that contains properties, one of them is an array of objects which has an object property of its own. There are redundant properties and I'd like to reduce the amount of data in the view. Is there a best practice I can follow?

Comment: how you are showing in the view?

Comment: Referencing the scope variable's properties to display in multiple parts of the view.

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#pick This appears to be a good solution, but is there an Angular way of doing this?

Comment: pass only needed data from service to controller

Comment: True, but what if we do not have access to the service?

Comment: Of course, there's no built-in way. Angular is a framework, not a library. There are several helper functions but nothing nearly that specific. So it is a generic JS question.